# How to write a daily status report mail to manager

Tags: communication

I am a software engineer of 7+ years of experience and working in a application in which only 2 resources. My reporting manager is busy with other work and on daily basis we have very little communication, only once or twice a day. He just tells me verbally what changes he needs or forwards some email to me provide by the clients to look into an issue.

I want to know how to give a effective daily reporting to the manger which gives him a clear idea of how honestly and sincerely I have worked the entire day to fulfil his requirement.

For example, he says "I am forwarding a email and you need to do custom pagination in the entire application as per the mail shared by client". When we meet in the evening how should I tell him what I have done for the entire day.

Comment: What did your boss say when you asked? Have you talked to him about what he is looking for? Without a bit more information about how your boss wants to receive an update, I'm not really sure this is meaningfully answerable.

Comment: You can get a ticket tracker, put all tasks in the ticket (the ones you discovered at the beginning and the ones that came up during the work) and then log time against each ticket.

Comment: Does your boss want a detalied report at all? This is not clear in your description, it's also possible you want to give it on your own -> "a clear idea of how honestly and sincerely I have worked" somewhat sounds like "look boss, I didn't watch cat videos but I really did what you told me" - you shouldn't make it sound like that. If he requests a report then ask him how detailed he wants it to be. Often bosses can't understand over-detailed things and don't have enough time to read it.

Answer (score 2):

keep a daily log with TODO section, updating it as you go.

for example, if you get a new task, ask how urgent is it and position with TODO section accordingly.
Each task you perform in the day, goes on that days section:

incomplete one`s get work in progress status, perhaps with subsections of each major part of the assignment worked on during the day

Task that got complete that day - get complete status

Comment: Also refer to your `git commit`-s in your daily report email

Answer (score -1):

It's slightly unclear what you're asking. Are you saying your boss does not know what you did? Or are you saying you'd like to let your boss know you are doing things?

Either way, wouldn't delivery of these tasks be a indicator to your boss that you are doing work? Or are you saying you are so flooded that tasks would not be fulfilled on a timely basis?

I think you should instead ask to sit down with your boss. Tell him what you are feeling and what you would like to do about it. *"Boss, you are adding a lot of tasks and it is hard to prioritize. I have 15 to do tasks and I am not sure which is more important. How would you like me to do these?"*